# Jqxdatatable : keep or recover the original names of an HTML table of inputs

Tags: javascript, forms, jqwidget, jqxwidgets

I'm new with jqwidgets

I have an html table in a form and the cells of this table are of inputs type
the html is constructed in Java via a JSP

These inputs in the table are submitted by this form when a button is pressed
(all fields are submitted with a specific name)

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxdatatable/index.htm

I am using jqxDataTable plugin to easily replace and customize this HTML Table already constructed on my page
and it works well, the right value is in the right cell

but i lost the name of the input
jqxDataTable transforms the inputs in the cell in a simple div
and consequently, removes the name of this input, and it is a problem for the submission...

i use a cellsrendrer, 
so i can put a new input in the cells of my table
but i need to recover the old name and the old id of the input (in the previous HTML table) 
in order to associate to the new input in the new table (Jqx) and to be able to submit it with the right name

Is it possible to do this ?

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find a way to answer to this problem

i use jqxgrid instead of jqxdatatable
and i follow this demo example :

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/loadfromtable.htm

so I create an array of row-objects with the input names
during the loop
as it is done in data for the array of data

and then I use this new array in the cell renderer with an input